# x-editable: remove ".editable-unsaved" class

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I am using x-editable for client side only, and after I select a day from the date popup, a class called "id_date" is added to the input. I attempt to remove the class, but it doesn't work. The class will continue to be threre.

```
$("#id_date").editable({
                     send: 'never',
                     success: function(response, newValue) {
                            ...
                            ...
                            $('#id_id_date').val(date_str);
                            $('#id_id_date').removeClass('editable-unsaved');
                     }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need the '.' with removeClass('.editable-unsaved')

Try: `$('#id_id_date').removeClass('editable-unsaved');`

Comment: Event I fix the code this way, it still does NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.4.1, there is an option called **unsavedclass**. If you set that to **null**, it won't apply the "editable-unsaved" class.